# Deserialize none standard Json with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json

I have to deserialize into a object the following json string:

```
var jsonString = @"[[{""OU2CJ3-UBRYG-KCPVS6"":{""cost"":""27187.08000"",""vol_exec"":""3.40000000"",""fee"":""27.18708"",""avg_price"":""7996.20000""}}]]";
```

Into a model, for instance like the following one :

```
public class OrderInfo
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public Info Info { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public decimal avg_price { get; set; }

    public decimal cost { get; set; }

    public decimal fee { get; set; }

    public decimal vol_exec { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried without success with this kind of code:

```
var nodes = JsonNode.Parse(jsonString);
foreach (var order in nodes[0].AsArray())
{
  // ??
}
```

Or :

```
var info = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<OrderInfo>(jsonString);
```

How can I handle a Json without clear {"Property": "name"} structure by using System.Text.Json framework ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `Info` class isn't correct. The values coming in the JSON are strings since they are wrapped with double quotes. So it should look like this:

```
public class Info
{
    public string avg_price { get; set; }
    public string cost { get; set; }
    public string fee { get; set; }
    public string vol_exec { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly, this JSON is actually an array of arrays.

Thirdly, you can use a Dictionary to cope with the changing property names.

So to deserialise, you can do something like this:

```
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Info>[][]>(jsonString);

foreach (var element in result)
{
    foreach (var innerElement in element)
    {
        foreach(var dictionaryItem in innerElement)
        {
            var key = dictionaryItem.Key;
            var info = dictionaryItem.Value;
            
            var avgPrice = info.avg_price;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code would be much more simple if you use Newtonsoft.Json, but since you are using Text.Json this code could be enough for your json

```
    var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<Dictionary<string,Info>>>>(jsonString);

    Info info = data[0][0].Values.First();

    decimal cost = info.Cost;
```

if you have several items, this code is more generic

```
List<OrderInfo> infos = jsonParsed.SelectMany(d => d.ToList())
    .SelectMany(v => ((JObject)v).Properties()
    .Select(d => new OrderInfo { OrderId = d.Name, Info = d.Value.ToObject<Info>()})
    .ToList())
    .ToList();
```

class Info

```
public partial class Info
{
    public string cost { set { Cost = Convert.ToDecimal(value); } }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    public string vol_exec { set { VolExec = Convert.ToDecimal(value); } }
    public decimal VolExec { get; set; }

    public string fee { set { Fee = Convert.ToDecimal(value); } }
    public decimal Fee { get; set; }

    public string avg_price { set { AvgPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(value); } }
    public decimal AvgPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Indeed I'm trying to "play" with Text.Json as my utlimate goal is to minimize (avoid?) the mermory allocation implied by the deserialization process. It seems  Text.Json with net6.0 and source generator can significatlly improved this... but I guess I need to go with Utf8JsonReader directly

Comment: @GuillaumeParis Text.Json maybe faster in some cases, but it is only because it doesn't have anything. For casses more complicated then "Hello World", you basically have to create your own serializer. So I prefer Newtonsoft.Json where ANY complicated case will need only a couple of lines of code. It contains already almost all code that software developers need.